# Is there any effective way to analyse the inner loop's time complexity(Big-O)?

Tags: time-complexity

```cpp
int j=2;
int sum=0;
while(j<n){
    int k=j;
    while(k<n){
        sum+=k;
        k*=k;
    }
    j+=log(k);
}
```

I meet some trouble when I analyse the inner loop's time complexity.

Comment: outer loop is easy - after inner loop possible value of k is large than n-1 and less than (n-1)^2, so outer loop complexity is n/log(n).

Comment: But I have trouble to analyse the inner loop's time complexity. Please.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the sequence of values k takes on across the loop is j, j<sup>2</sup>, j<sup>4</sup>, j<sup>8</sup>, etc. More generally, across m iterations of the loop, the value of k is j<sup>2<sup>m</sup></sup>.

The loop stops when k exceeds n. Equating, rearranging, and using properties of logarithms gives us that

> j<sup>2<sup>m</sup></sup> = n
>
> 2<sup>m</sup> = log<sub>j</sub> n = log n / log j
>
> m = log (log n / log j) = log log n - log log j

In other words, the inner loop runs a total of log log n - log log j iterations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is the final answer nloglogn/logn? @templatetypedef